# exctracting a variable from a jquery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to extract the variable `response` from the `mentionsInput()` method and using it outside this method, but when I try an `alert()` on this variable it's empty.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    var choix = $('#choixaide').val();
    var choix_sous_theme1 = $('#choix_sous_theme1aide').val();

    $('textarea.mention1').mentionsInput('val', function(text) {                
        var response = text;
    });

    alert(response);
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Put the `alert()` inside the function?

Comment: Uhh, why not `var response = $(el).val(); alert(response);` what's the callback for ?

Comment: I think the problem is you are declaring the variable response inside the method mentionsInput. Try to use a clousure, declare the variable response outside the method and assign it inside it. I'm not confident this will work but that's a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have it now, `response` is only available within the scope of your `mentionsInput` method, but not outside of it.

Additionally, when running your code, I see the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mentionsInput is not a function"...

Are you sure you've properly loaded the [jquery.mentionsInput UI component](https://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/)?  You'll need to solve for this error first, if you are also encountering this.

Then, you'll need to declare the variable `response` prior to and outside of your `mentionsInput` method, and then set it within `mentionsInput`. The value set for `response` should then be available in the same scope as your `alert` call.

Comment: I declare outside but it still not works

Comment: var response;
    $('textarea.mention1').mentionsInput('val', function(text) {                
    var response = text;
    });
    
         
     
    alert(response);

Comment: @simo9900 I've edited for further debugging.

Comment: thanks, I found an other solution. I will try it after and communicate the results

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          var choix = $('#choixaide').val();
          var choix_sous_theme1 = $('#choix_sous_theme1aide').val();

          var response = $('textarea.mention1').val();

          alert(response);

        });
```

Comment: No the method had to be like this  $('textarea.mention1').mentionsInput('val', function(text) {